# Mockito / PowerMockito conflict (possible) when used with SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring, mocking

Hello I am trying to use PowerMockito and Mockito with @SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class.
I am not sure where there is a conflict. I've managed to use just mockito ok but
require to use PowerMockito for statics.

The following trace is obtained:

org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedStubbingException: 
Unfinished stubbing detected here:
-> at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.PowerMockitoCore.doAnswer(PowerMockitoCore.java:31)

...

The essential parts of the test code are as below:

The failure is at line 2.
If lines 1 and 3 are removed, the test works ok.
if SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class is replaced with PowerMockRunner.class, the test also works.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
@PrepareForTest({StatFactory.class})
public class TestMain {

@Test
public void testGetStatic() throws Exception {

    PowerMockito.mockStatic(StatFactory.class);    // 1
    StatsFactory sf = mock(StatsFactory.class);
    Main main = new Main();
    PowerMockito.doReturn(false).when(StatFactory.class, "testFunction");  // 3
    Mockito.when(sf.ok()).thenReturn(5);           // 2

    boolean ret = main.getData();
}       

pom.xml
...
<properties>
    <java-version>1.6</java-version>
    <org.springframework-version>3.1.0.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
    <powermock.version>1.4.9</powermock.version>
</properties>
...
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.7</version>
     <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>    
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.5</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>    
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
    <version>${powermock.version}</version>
     <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
      <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
      <version>${powermock.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **PowerMock Rules**

Here you have an example: http://www.jayway.com/2010/12/28/using-powermock-with-spring-integration-testing/

That's the problem of having static fields. They are hard to test.

Here is an entry of Misko Hevery which explains why: 
http://misko.hevery.com/2008/12/15/static-methods-are-death-to-testability/